# block UI while download unfinished

Tags: jquery, asp.net, blockui

I want to block the page until the download is finished and then unblock it. I write this code but after 1 sec it unblocks UI and download is still unfinished.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var fileDownloadCheckTimer;
    function blockUIForDownload() {
        if (IsCookiesEnable()) {
            var token = new Date().getTime(); //use the current timestamp as the token value
             $.blockUI({ message: 'لطفا منتظر بمانید تا فایل مورد نظر شما دانلود شود', fadeIn: 0 });
            fileDownloadCheckTimer = window.setInterval(function() {
                var cookieValue = $.cookie('fileDownloadToken');
                // alert(cookieValue);

                if (cookieValue != null)
                    finishDownload();
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    function IsCookiesEnable() {
        var cookieEnabled = (navigator.cookieEnabled) ? true : false;

        if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled == "undefined" && !cookieEnabled) {
            document.cookie = "testcookie";
            cookieEnabled = (document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie") != -1) ? true : false;
        }
        return (cookieEnabled);
    }

    function finishDownload() {
        window.clearInterval(fileDownloadCheckTimer);
        $.cookie('fileDownloadToken', null);
        $.unblockUI();

    }
```

I use asp.net, C# and blockUi plugin.

Comment: How is the `fileDownloadToken` cookie set?

Comment: yes,it a cookie on server side seted when doenload finish.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with blockUI. Is your problem that `finishDownload` is being called before the download is finished? Have you verified this by an alert or a log inside the function itself? If so, is `if(cookieValue == token)` the only place where `finishDownload` is being called? What is the value of `cookieValue` when `finishDownload` is being called?

Comment: After your edit, all of my questions above still apply.

Comment: my problem is:after download finished then unblock ui

Comment: I realize this. Would you be able to answer some of the questions I posted in my comment?

Comment: the result of this alert is null                                               if (cookieValue != null) {
                    alert(cookieValue);
                    finishDownload();
                }

Comment: This is of course surprising since you're verifying explicitly that it isn't. Could it be that at some previous point you've set the cookie to the string `'null'`? Because you wouldn't be able to tell `alert('null')` from `alert(null)` by looking at it, and `'null'` is not `null` so it would bypass your check.

Comment: alert(cookieValue) result is undefind